# Check if NSTextView has been edited

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Is there a way to get notified when a NSTextView gets modified?. In a NSTextField I just set the target for the default sent action and works perfectly, but I don't see any sent actions on a NSTextView.

Comment: I don't think there's a delegate method for this, could you not just keep polling it and compare values?

Comment: I think you are right let m check

Comment: I could not find any delegate method that will make me aware of a change

Comment: That's what I was saying, so you could poll it at your own interval in a loop (on a different thread!) and create your own psuedo-notification system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSTextView inherits from NSText, which conforms to the NSTextDelegate protocol. Look it up in the docs. The method you are looking for is: `- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification` which you can either implement in your TextView's delegate or get by registering for a "NSTextDidChangeNotification" notification.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSTextField and override the textDidChange method that it has.

The delegate will tell you when it will start editing and when it will finish editing. But the control itself gets the textDidChange method called on itself.

Subclass it and override the method

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
```

then you could set a flag that you can access externally.