# How do I check when a NSTextView changes if I have two text views?

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, nstextview

In a macOS app with two NSTextView, I am trying to check when a textView changes, so far I have done this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mainTextField: NSTextView!
    @IBOutlet var findPanelFindTextView: NSTextView!

    func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            print("Hello!") // works only with mainTextField
        }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainTextField.delegate = self // for textDidChange
        findPanelFindTextField.delegate = self // for textDidChange
    }

}
```

Only the first NSTextView (mainTextField) triggers the method textDidChange.

I already see this question [Check if NSTextView has been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873387/check-if-nstextview-has-been-edited) and that implementation works for my first textView but not for my second textView.

Comment: your code is fine except for "findPanelFindTextView" is not "findPanelFindTextField", also check to have attached the IBOutlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that you wrote findPanelFindTextField but it should be findPanelFindTextView, you should check the object that posted the notification, create a textView object from it but cast it from `Any` to `NSTextView` and then create a switch to check which textview is posting the notification:

```
@IBOutlet var mainTextView: NSTextView!
@IBOutlet var findPanelFindTextView: NSTextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainTextView.delegate = self
    findPanelFindTextView.delegate = self
}

func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else { return }
    switch textView {
    case mainTextView:
        print("mainTextView changed")
    case findPanelFindTextView:
        print("findPanelFindTextView changed")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Leo, you have been a great help to me